# First page in Book is forced to be Left Page

Tags: margins, books

I am using sharelatex.com for my thesis, and need my first page to be a right page. However, even though I specify in my documentclass that is should be 'openright', it still won't work!

```
\documentclass[openright, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\end{document}
```

This code generates the following result:

[image]

I just can't understand what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions of what the fault may be?

Comment: Well, you first page is a recto page, opening right.

Comment: Really? The picture was meant to demonstrate that the right margin was wider than the left. Then I assumed that it was a left page. I did not observe any change when I changed to "openleft" either

Comment: The screenshot you posted shows a right hand page. The rectangle on the right shows the space reserved for the outer marginal notes.

Comment: Haha, lol. Well, thank you! Do you know if it is possible to remove the margin note, as I want to have the inner margin as the widest one?

Comment: You can use package geometry to change the margins. But i really think this will look just bad for a two sided document.

Comment: Try `openany`. I'm not sure if `openleft` is an option, but the first page ***cannot*** open left, can it? What would it be the reverse of? There must be a page 1 in physical terms. You can't jump to its backside for 2.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not an answer but too long for a comment.

Basically every two sided book (in left-to-right style) starts with the first page on the right, as everyone else told you already

Regarding the extra-margin, it's kind of a balancing thing, since when the pages are open, the two inner margins "sum up" to the eye, so they have to be balanced by a thicker outer margin. Also the outer margin is meant as a place where margin notes can be, and finally a place where to rest thumbs while reading. So you need to have big ones.

This is an almost "standard" way to do things, albeit I have some books which do quite the opposite, or mess around the margins completely. Those are *special purpose books* eg, about typography, photography, and have specific needs to fulfil while doing so.

So if you want to mess around with the margins, first **you should know what you are doing** because "custom" placing in a "word-processor-style" usually result in something that can be really really ugly. If you want to and have time to enjoy the pleasure of reading some typography books (e.g. Bringhurst's *The elements of typographic style* or Felici's *Complete manual of typography*) it can be useful and teach you *how to* tweak the margins in order to obtain something well readable and beautiful.

If this is not the case (ie you don't have time, or don't want to learn some basic typography), I usually advice to let LaTeX do the job, since LaTeX is really good with typography. Of course there may be some problems which can require your attention (eg I feel that a4paper margins are a bit off and have to be reset), I recommend you become accustomed to the `geometry` package syntax, and try posting a more specific problem perhaps. But it's really easy to mess up the style and, instead of having one good document beautifully typeset, your document could stand out for its ugliness.